# How to rename changed files while merging branches and keep old versions?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-merge

Let's say that I have following file on my master branch

```
$ git checkout master
$ cat truth.txt
The Earth is flat
```

And its updated version on some branch (rebased on `master`)

```
$ git checkout magellan-dev
$ cat truth.txt
The Earth is a globe
```

I would like now to merge branch `magellan-dev` into `master`, but keep all the files changed as new files with different names. It could look like

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge megellan-dev --some-magic-flag
$ ls
truth.txt truth.txt.magellan-dev
```

The solution I found for a single file was to manually rename that file and checkout the previous

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge magellan-dev
$ mv truth.txt truth.txt.magellan-dev
$ git checkout HEAD^ truth.txt
$ git add truth.txt truth.txt.magellan-dev
```

But this badly generalizes for bigger amount of files. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wonder why you would like `truth.txt.magellan-dev`. If you are interested in its content, `git show magellan-dev:truth.txt` works without switching the branch. Also, you can run `git worktree add path/to/new/folder magellan-dev` to checkout `magellan-dev` under a new worktree `path/to/new/folder` so that you can see files of both branches, without cloning another repo.

Comment: I would like to add both versions to the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in to Git to do this.

You can handle *some* cases by using `git read-tree` to do the merge in the index, without resolving any conflicting changes.  But note that [even `git read-tree`'s 3-way merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_3_way_merge) will in some cases just pick one of the two endpoint versions of some file: if the merge base version (tree #1 as inserted into slot #1 in the index) of some file *F* matches one of the other two (staging slots 2 or 3), and *does not* match the version of *F* in the *other* of the two staging slots, `git read-tree` will collapse the three versions down to a single stage-zero slot, taking the modified file.

In other words, given your example with two different contents for `truth.txt`, we first need to know: *what does the merge base version say?*  If the merge base version of `truth.txt` exactly matches one of the two branch-tip versions, then *all* Git merge operations will just automatically take the other version.  Only when all three differ will Git leave all three in the index, so that you can achieve your desired result using some of Git's built-in helpers.

If that does not match up with your desires, you're stuck with building your own programs to deal with the various trees.  Note that you can make your own temporary index and use `git read-tree` to fill it, then use `git ls-files --stage` on however many temporary index files you used, plus of course the real index file, to compare entities.  That gives you a fast way to decide whether `truth.txt` is identical or different in any two trees read into any two index files.

(You could do all of this without using any of Git's internals, of course: just check out the commits in question in separate work-trees, and compare work-tree files.)